# Vue data referencing issue

Tags: vue.js

This is strange because it was just working last night, but basically I have a Vue app that's pulling JSON from my backend. Code below. The strange part is that while the loadData function is running and I see the 'Loaded Data' message in console along with the list of items from the JSON, I then get a console error saying 'items is not defined'. I must have made a subtle typo or some dumb change but I can't find it anywhere!! Any ideas?

HTML snippet:

```
<div id="app">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Query</th>
                            <th>Initiated By</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <div v-for="item in items">
                                <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ item.query }}</td>
                                <td>{{ item.user }}</td>
                                <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

(And then `<script src="app.js"></script>` right before `</body>`)

JS code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: [],
        interval: null
    },
    methods: {
        loadData: function () {
            $.get('http://localhost:4567/getQueue', function (response) {
                this.items = response.results;
                console.log("Loaded data.")
                console.log(response.results)
            }.bind(this));
        }
    },

    created: function () {
        console.log("Loading data...")

        this.loadData();

        console.log(items)

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            this.loadData();
        }.bind(this), 3000); 
    },

    beforeDestroy: function(){
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
});
```

Comment: Are items being rendered after data gets loaded?

Comment: I would think so - I'm loading `app.js` in my HTML after the `v-for` html references. The weird thing is that this code worked yesterday. I was just told on Gitter that it's because of not using a callback or promise, so I'm looking into that...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error

> items is not defined

because of following line:

```
created: function () {
    console.log("Loading data...")

    this.loadData();

    console.log(items)   <== this should be console.log(this.items)
```

Comment: Ah yes - however I'm still showing `Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during the render.`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a few issues in my code.

1) As was pointed out by Saurabh, I forgot to put `this.items` instead of `items`.

2) `this` can't be referenced inside of the function I defined as I have it... instead, the function has to be defined with `=>`, for example:

```
$.get('http://localhost:4567/getQueue').then((response) => {
        this.items = response.data.results;
        console.log("loadData finished - items length is: "+this.items.length)
    })
```

3) The big error I had was that my div bind with items was *inside* the table tag, which apparently isn't okay to do. Instead I applied the Vue binds to the existing tags (table, tr).